# Downloading an image to client side using PHP

Tags: php, download, imagedownload

I have say 5 URLs of five images available from Google search. Now I wish to download them on client side. Any way to do it using PHP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. PHP doesn't download to clients. The client (i.e. a browser) can download from a server, and the server may use PHP to send the data.

[edit]

1. To send a single image, you must set the right header, to specifiy
   the content type of the image. See
   http://www.ehow.com/how_7280601_send-php-image-file.html
2. To send multiple images, you could send a multipart response.
   Unfortunately support for this type of response is poor. Don't use
   it.
3. Or you can just send a html page with `<img>` tags in it. The url of
   the image can be a direct file location, or a PHP script that sends
   a single image, like in 1.

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting. What should I do to download images when the user visits the page ?

Comment: Can you update your answers with a small example ? I am using CURL to get the image URLs. Now I need to download those images when client visits them. What options do I have ?

Comment: Just include them in the page? Your question doesn't make sense. Provide more context by editing the question.