# How to export images to local folder using php

Tags: php

how to export images to the local folder using PHP, my all the data is in server system. How i export uploaded images in client system ?  Please give me solution. I am using Php.  Thanks to all.

Comment: use `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: from server to client? where does your php code run? server or client?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094080/download-files-from-server-php

Comment: my php code run in server.   I will try other answers given by you. Thanks once again

Comment: like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12689043/4669350

Comment: 'PHP doesn't download to clients. The client (i.e. a browser) can download from a server, and the server may use PHP to send the data.' ? So, do u want which one? download form client or  send to client from server?

Comment: sir, i want  to send images to client from server

Comment: You can't do this, the only way is to provide download link of the image to user, then user can save it in the local folders.

Comment: I did not get the result. Pls. If I use downlink and  image is not downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Either you keep a zipped file for images. And request the url directly. No role of php, if the images folder is static.
In case the image folder is not static, and the images are added/deleted, you can create a zip using php zip library. That would be the best option in order to  download multiple images at clients machine.

You can use the code as below. The code below is from another stack overflow post at [How to zip a whole folder using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php)

```
// Get real path for our folder
$rootPath = realpath('folder-to-zip');

// Initialize archive object
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('file.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

// Create recursive directory iterator
/** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file)
{
    // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
    if (!$file->isDir())
    {
        // Get real and relative path for current file
        $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
        $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

        // Add current file to archive
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
    }
}

// Zip archive will be created only after closing object
$zip->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/724564/4669350

```
function save_image($inPath,$outPath)
{ //Download images from remote server
    $in=    fopen($inPath, "rb");
    $out=   fopen($outPath, "wb");
    while ($chunk = fread($in,8192))
    {
        fwrite($out, $chunk, 8192);
    }
    fclose($in);
    fclose($out);
}

save_image('http://www.someimagesite.com/img.jpg','image.jpg');
```